# ASP.NET : Configuration Error(Server Error in '/' Application.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, web-config

this error got me crazy ! i was working on my `registration.aspx` page and all of sudden this error came up and i spend days to solve it but nothing has worked ! at the end i delete my `registration.aspx` just to check if the project still working without it but nothing has changed !

the error shows red in line 15 :

```
> Server Error in '/' Application.
> 
> Configuration Error
> 
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
> configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
> specific error details below and modify your configuration file
> appropriately. 
> 
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element 'authentication'.
> 
> Source Error: 
> 
> 
> Line 13:   <system.web> 
> Line 14:     <pages validateRequest="false">
> Line 15:       <authentication mode="None"/> 
> Line 16:         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/> 
> Line 17:            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

the `web.config` page :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyWebsite\MyWebsite\MyWebsite\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false">
      <authentication mode="None"/>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Beta configuration -->
    <add key="STSHost" value="auth.beta.agiv.be"/>
    <!-- See documentation https://auth.beta.agiv.be/framework/Documentation/index.html for a list of consumable services and their realms -->
    <add key="STSRealm" value="urn:agiv.be/salvador"/>
    <add key="ApplicationRealm" value="%Application realm%"/>
    <!-- Production Configuration, uncomment for use -->
    <!--
      <add key="STSHost" value="auth.agiv.be"/> 
      <add key="STSRealm" value="urn:agiv.be/sts"/>       
      <add key="ApplicationRealm" value="%Application realm%"/>
    -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client/>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateEndpointBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <!-- Change this value to your certificate, and put this behavior on your client endpoint-->
            <clientCertificate findValue="%Certificate Subject Distinguished Name%" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

please any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<authentication>` is not a child of `<pages>`, it should be nested within `<system.web>`

`compilation` and `httpRuntime` also need to be moved out.

Try this

```
 <authentication mode="None"/>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 <pages validateRequest="false">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

You also have two `compilation` attributes. Remove the second one.

Comment: Hopefully he has a </pages> somewhere later on

Comment: @n8wrl Why "hopefully"? Look at the question, it's there.

Comment: Yes it's working ! you have saved my life thank you so much ! do know how this error developed ? like i haven't touch the `web.cofig` at all !

Comment: @user5067119, if you don't use version control (Git, SVN, etc), it might be a good time to start. Then when something breaks, you can compare it to the last known working copy.

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you it doesn't recognize the `<authentication>` element under `<pages>`. That's because `<authentication>` needs to be directly under `<system.web>`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" /> <!-- This is the line that needed to be moved -->
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <pages validateRequest="false">                
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
                <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Make sure you pay attention to the error message and [check the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397(v=vs.100).aspx) when you get errors like that.

Answer (score -1):

Check the application pool, it looks like you've put it in Integrated mode rather than Classic.